# on opening specific .java file in a project , Netbeans 7.4 ide is not responding

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I did a FXML project in netbeans 7.4, upto two days back everything is fine. Yesterday when i opened  a specific .java file in that project, that .java file is opened, after few seconds netbeans ide is not responding at all. Netbeans ide is not responding for that .java file only for rest of files it is perfect. In that .java file, i created many objects and it contains nearly 7K lines of code. when ever i open that specific .java file CPU usage is increasing some times 100% also.

Just i want to known the reason why it is happening for that specific file only. Is there a way to solve these

Comment: You need to reconsider your code in that java file, a class ideally should not be of 7k lines, what you can do is separate the logic by applying Single Responsibility principle, don't create a GOD object.

Comment: As pathfinder said, please divide you class into smaller classes specifying different functionality to them. In the mean time, you may consider, to change workspace or try to compile and run the java file from `terminal`, just to be sure if the problem is with the code or the IDE !

Comment: i installed netbeans 7.0.1 version and opened code in that, now it's working fine.

Comment: please tell me, without running the project why it is taking more memory.